# 1 pixel line height difference between Firefox and Chrome

Tags: asp.net, css, firefox, google-chrome

Working on a new site design in asp.net with master pages. Header of the page is a 35px tall "menu bar" which contains an asp menu control rendered as an unordered list.

The selected menu item is styled with a differenct colored background and 2px border around the left top and right sides. The bottom of the selected menu item should line up with the bottom of the menu bar so the selected "tab" looks as if it flows into the content beneath. Looks fine in firefox and IE but in chrome the "tab" seems to be 1 pixel higher than the bottom of the menu bar.

Just wondering if there is some sort of bug I dont know about.

I realize that you will most likely need code to help with this problem so ill post up the css as soon as possible.

EDIT:

here is the css for the menu...

```
div.hideSkiplink
{     
    width:40%;
    float:right;
    height:35px;
}

div.menu
{
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    display:inline;
}

div.menu ul
{
    list-style: none;
}

div.menu ul li
{
    margin:0px 4px 0px 0px;
}

div.menu ul li a, div.menu ul li a:visited
{
  color: #ffffff;
  display: block;
  margin-top:0px;
  line-height: 17px;
  padding: 1px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

div.menu ul li a:hover
{
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-top: 1px solid #fff;
  border-right: 1px solid #fff;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-left: 1px solid #fff;
}




div.menu ul li a:active
{
 background:#ffffff !important;
 border-top:2px solid #a10000;
 border-right:2px solid #a10000;
 border-bottom: none;
 border-left:2px solid #a10000;
 color: #000000 !important;
 font-weight:bold;

}


div.menu ul a.selected
{
  color: #000000 !important;
  font-weight:bold;
}

div.menu ul li.selected
{
 background:#ffffff !important;
 border-top:2px solid #a10000;
 border-right:2px solid #a10000;
 border-bottom: none;
 border-left:2px solid #a10000;
}

div.menu ul li.selected a:hover
{
  border: none;
}
```

The selected classes are added to the li and a elements via jquery...

Here is a screenshot of the problem...
The chrome example is on the top and u can see 1px of red border below the tab. 
On the bottom is the firefox image where everything looks OK.

[image]

EDIT:

After playing around with this a bit more, I have discovered that it is actually the "header" div itself that is growing by 1px in chrome... This seems very strange to me.

Comment: Some CSS and accompanying screen shots of the differences would be helpful.

Comment: I will post them this evening for sure. I was just curious if there was anything obvious that would cause this in the mean time.

Comment: css and screenshot added. Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: It would be nice if you put this on fiddler so we could play with it and see the HTML.

Comment: Im not really familiar with fiddler... I can say that if I tweak the line-height for the "a" element(current 17px in my css above) and set it to 18px it looks fine in chrome...but of course its 1px too tall in firefox...I have also tested this in IE and it works fine there as well as is.

Comment: By fiddler he means http://jsfiddle.net

You can post the HTML and CSS there and we can easily test, and, fiddle.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It's important to realize that web pages will always render differently in different browsers. Acheiving pixel perfection is futile, and nowadays I try to explain to my clients what kind of cost is involved to make every browser render the site exactly alike. More often now, they understand that IE6 and FF4 won't ever render any page the same way. We must try to make our clients understand and embrace the dynamics of the web.

Progressive enhancement and graceful degradation. Peace.

Comment: Agreed. However, I must assume that this issue is caused by an error in my code that I have overlooked. I am really a beginner when it comes to design and dont fully trust my css skills lol.

Comment: Don't underestimate your own power. :-) Ask yourself (or the client) what will benefit the client the most - you finding that pixel or bringing them more functionality, more tests or something else useful. Time is money is quality.

Comment: I would agree with you once again and those points are surely something to keep in mind. However, in this particular case, I am the client and this project is merely an opportunity to enhance my own skills.

Comment: Niklas, while everything you said IS true, errors like these aren't because of graceful degradation. They are here, because something is wrong in the code. People should distinguish between pixel-perfection for whole website and pixel-perfection for parts they have good control of.

Comment: @Adam Kiss, any idea what would cause this issue?

Comment: I agree, Adam. Sometimes we actually just do stuff wrong and we have to find out how to fix it. Good point to separate the two types of pixel chasing! Stephen: Ah, that's a bummer, can't point at the client this time. :-) Good luck in finding the issue, you will find it and learn from it!

Comment: If you downvote - please leave a comment to improve future postings. Thanks.

Comment: While I agree with the motto, this is not an answer to the question and does not help to solve the problem. Pixel perfection is possible.

Comment: This answer does not answer the question, sure I agree with you on some level but perhaps the project requires for the browsers to match at single pixel perfection.. this can be achieved if the client requires it

Comment: This answer simply does not help. Just help with the answer or don't post anything

Comment: I agree with the point, but its not a valid solution to the asked question.

Comment: The answer below should be the correct answer.  While it is difficult to maintain pixel perfection there is a solution to this problem and in some cases it is worth the extra time and effort to do so.  In other words, don't just give up.

Answer (score 71):

None of these answers solve the problem.

Set:

```
line-height: 1;
padding-top: 2px;
```

Because webkit & mozilla rendering engines implement line height differently do not use this it to manipulate measurement for single line items.

For items like menus, buttons and especially really small notification bubbles, reset the line-height to normal and use padding or margins to make them behave the same.

Here's a JSFiddle illustrating this issue:
http://jsfiddle.net/mahalie/BSMZe/6/

Comment: Fwiw, I think this is the best answer of the bunch. { line-height: normal; padding: xyx } solves this bug.

Comment: This is actually an answer, not a reason to give up (like the accepted answer). If you let line-height reserve the space, you indeed run into the odd pixel difference here and there. Using padding/margin to reserve the space, solves this.

Comment: just saved my day ...!!!! line-height: normal; did the trick for me :)))))) i was getting reaaally frustrated...

Comment: Simply by adding "line-height: 1;" fixed the issue I was having! Brilliant!

Comment: Upvoted. Although I couldn't agree more with the choosen answer, I was working on one of those cases where I was asked to make it show exactly the same way, pixel perfect, and your answer put an end to the craziness. Feels like the 90's :\ Anyway, thank you!

Comment: Your answer is perfect, so I upvoted it. By the way, in Opera it shows the icon (FontAwesome) 1px upper in reference to Chrome or Firefox. Do you know why is that?

Comment: What if I need to move an element? I'm using negative `margin-top:-3px` but on Firefox it needs to be `-4px`.

Comment: Using this strategy, there's still a difference between browsers that needs to be accounted for. E.g. On MacOS, Firefox vs Chrome, the padding-top trick works in one, then screws up the other regardless of line-height reset.

Answer (score 14):

I just had this same problem, and I solved it by explicitly setting the line height and font size in `<li>` element that contains the `<a>` elements that are the tab links. Hope this helps someone in the future.

(edited html links)

Comment: um, it stripped my tag references. line height and font size should be set on th li tag that contains the link elements.

Answer (score 3):

This is a common issue I run into on some of my sites... when it's IE having the pixel difference, I can usually just add a pixel of margin/padding in my IE stylesheet. But when it's Safari/FireFox/Chrome, I usually just live with the pixel and make the FireFox crowd happy (for now—until Webkit rules the web!), even though it looks a little strange in the opposite browser.

However, you might also want to check out the line-height values (or add a value, if there isn't one already) on the containing `ul` or `div` element. Tinkering with that allowed me to get the padding exactly the same in FireFox, Chrome and IE.

Comment: I will check out the line heights on the ul for sure and see if this helps. I really wanted to avoid having multiple stylesheets for various browsers.

Comment: It's almost inevitable nowadays once you do anything more advanced than type 'Hello, world' ;-)

Comment: Please don't do the multiple stylesheet dance without trying lots of other stuff first. Some vendor specific prefixes - sure, but no loading of different files unless really, really necessary.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the solution that I found in [this page](http://www.aheadcreative.com/removing-unwanted-button-padding-in-firefox/) :

```
   button::-moz-focus-inner {
        border: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I have been fighting with this problem for a little while now, and almost gave up on the pixel. However it's come to me in one of those eurika moments: if you get the tab lined up perfectly in Chrome (which leaves an overlap in Firefox), set the ul height to the height of the li (including any padding), you can remove the offending pixels in Firefox by setting overflow to hidden on the ul.

Hope this helps someone out there!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with my main tabs displaying them in Chrome, they were one pixel off in height and there for leaving an ugly slit between the tabs and the white background of the mainframe.

I solved the problem by giving the tab div an upper margin with a floated value. First tried margin-top:0.1px nothing then 0.2 etc. until with an upper margin of 0.5 everything displayed fine over all the major browsers.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same issue, turns out chrome had zoom set to 110% and that was breaking the menu. I noticed it when I fired up chrome on another computer and it looked fine.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and it was due to using ems for font sizes, margins and padding.  The browsers were rounding the ems differently and causing intermittent off-by-1px issues all over the site depending on the length of content.  Once I changed everything to pixel measurements my problems went away.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I've come across this problem in relation to text with transparent backgrounds.

I couldn't get any of the above solutions to work consistently so I ended up using a webkit hack to give those browsers a different line-height. Like so:

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
    .your-class {
        line-height:20px;
    }
}
```

Eww, hacky! I try to avoid CSS hacks but I just couldn't find another way. I hope that helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this issue with a web font I was working with by setting the following:

```
.some-class {
    display: inline-table;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Granted it's a bit hacky but does the job. It does mean though you will have target styles specifically for Internet Explorer

Answer (score 0):

try using display:block with the a element"
eg...

```
<li><a href="">Link</a></li>
```

css:

```
li{line-height:20px;}/*example only*/

li a{display:block;}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is the only way , use different styles for different browsers the problematic sections

```
/* FOR MOZILLA */
@-moz-document url-prefix() { 
.selector {
 color:lime;
}
}
/* FOR CHROME */
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) { 
/* Safari and Chrome, if Chrome rule needed */
.container {
 margin-top:100px;
}
/* Safari 5+ ONLY */
::i-block-chrome, .container {
 margin-top:0px;
}``
```

Answer (score 0):

if `line-height` is used for vertically aligning text in a container (which it shouldn't), then consistent behaviour across browsers can be enforced like this:

```
line-height: 75px
height: 75px
overflow: hidden
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also make different css for mozila:

```
-moz-height:2em;
```

one can also use:

```
@-moz-document url-prefix{
    // your css
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I might be a beginner in CSS, but I found the same problem in W3Cschools.com, in one of their examples.

http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_sprites_hover_nav

this example is about image sprites. You can see in this example, in Chrome, the home icon and prev icon have the 1px divider line, which is not the case in Firefox.

It seems that in Chrome the pixel count is 1pixel different to that of Firefox.