# CSS Problem between FireFox and Chrome

Tags: css, firefox, google-chrome

Okay this is a continuation of my previous question found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4439537/1-pixel-line-height-difference-between-firefox-and-chrome).

I have an asp.net menu control styled as an unordered list that is rendering slightly differently in chrome and firefox. I am convinced this is due to an error in my css as opposed to a quirk between the two browsers.

I have recreated the menu [here](http://jsfiddle.net/EdnKZ/2/).

Here is a screen shot depicting the problem(Chrome on top, FireFox on the bottom):

[image]

Any Ideas??

Comment: have you tried to adapt the line-height?

Comment: Tried tweaking line heights on the "li" and "a" elements...I can get it to look fine in each browser seperately using different line height values but cant get them to play nicely together...didnt want to load different css files based on current browser(maybe the reality is that this just cant be avoided in production situations?)...

Comment: what i do in this cases is append a class with the browser and os to the body.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because your provided [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/EdnKZ/2/) seemed rather hopeless in IE, I made new CSS to go with your HTML, trying to keep the behaviour of your old CSS:

(tested in IE7/8, Firefox, Chrome)

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jJ6uD/)

Your HTML (slightly changed: `href="#"`/`class="selected"`):

```
<div class="header">
    <div class="headerInner">

        <div class="hideSkipLink">
         <div class="menu">   
          <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Test 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#" class="selected">Test 2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Test 3</a></li>
            </ul>
         </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

New CSS:

```
.header {
    font: 12px/18px Tahoma,arial,sans-serif;
    height: 33px;
    background: #666;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #a10000;
}
.header ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 8px 0 0 0;
    list-style: none;
    height: 33px
}
.header li {
    display: inline
}
.header li a {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 0 0 4px;
    padding: 3px 20px 0 20px;
    height: 22px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none
}
.header li a:hover {
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    border-bottom: none;
    padding: 2px 19px 0 19px;
}
.header li .selected, .header li a:active {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #000;
    background: #fff;
    border: 2px solid #a10000 !important;
    border-bottom: none !important;
    padding: 3px 20px 0 20px !important;
}
```

Comment: Thank you taking the time to do that! I am still have a similar issue though...Still works fine in FireFox but now, in Chrome, the menu Elements are way below the header div...

Comment: I see that you have tested this in all 3 browsers...I must have another issue elsewhere. I will look into that further and post back when I figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Check the padding on the element. They all seem shifted over a few pixels. Also, could you give us the CSS please?

Comment: You can use Stephen's jsFiddle link to obtain the CSS

Comment: the padding should be ok...I think the shift you are seeing is caused by the alignment images which I cropped from seperate screenshots