# HTML5 Video incorrect size when display in Chrome?

Tags: html, google-chrome, html5-video

I have an video file I'm using as a html5 video element. The problem is the dimensions are different from what my mac reports and what is shown in chrome. Chrome's 'auto' height is 1 pixel off from the mac height.

Safari sets the video at the correct height.

Is this a bug or is there something I can do about this? Thanks. The video was created with MPEG Streamclip if that helps.

[image: img]

Comment: You may want to look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/4450577/67566

Comment: @JamesBlack HTML is one thing... this is a video.