# Different font height in Firefox and Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, firefox

I want to measure the font height of an html element using jQuery.

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g9uKq/196/)

```
//HTML
<h1 id="fonty">Size of font in pixels?</h1>

//CSS
#fonty {
    font-size: 8px;
    font-family: Arial;
}

//Javascript
var height = $("#fonty").height();
console.log(height);
```

The method works fine but I get different results in Chrome and Firefox. Is there a way to get the correct/identical font sizes in all browsers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [1 pixel line height difference between Firefox and Chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4439537/1-pixel-line-height-difference-between-firefox-and-chrome)

Answer (score 1):

The height of a font is not only measured with font-size but its valued up by font-size and line-height and padding values:

So, the different browsers have different default values like for [line-height 1px different in firefox and chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4439537/1-pixel-line-height-difference-between-firefox-and-chrome) so they may differ.

You may calculate them all by explicitly defining them.

Comment: Correct. `line-height: 1` will "fix" this problem.

Comment: Also, this is one of the reasons you want to use a general CSS reset set.

Comment: But now the method height() does only return the font size. I need the pixel height of the letters.

Comment: Yes. You need to add it.